# Sending Message Over TCP in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, tcp, client-server

I am using swift socket library with the following code:

```
let client:TCPClient = TCPClient(addr: "127.0.0.1", port: 8080)
var (success,errmsg)=client.connect(timeout: 1)
if success{
    var (success,errmsg)=client.send(str:"|~\0" )
    if success{
        let data=client.read(1024*10)
        if let d=data{
            if let str=String(bytes: d, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
                print(str)
            }
        }
    }else{
        print(errmsg)
    }
}else{
    print(errmsg)
}
```

The code works great but my problem is that the connection succeed only if the simulator is not on a real iphone (my iphone), but only on their simulators.
I don't know how to solve it and what is the problem.
When I print the errmsg it shows me:"connection timeout".

Comment: your ip is localhost.............

Comment: I changed it of course, still it dosen't work.. @Arbitur

Comment: which ip, to where? to your router? check if your router is reachable through that port

Comment: Yes it is, as I said, it works perfect in regular simulator, but not on my iphone... @Arbitur

Comment: without more information Im afraid I cant help you

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to set your host ip as the ip of your computer?

```
let client:TCPClient = TCPClient(addr: "your computer ip", port: 8080)
```

I guess that it works on simulator because the simulator share network with your real computer, so in case of connecting from external such as your phone I think you should try to replace localhost ip with the ip of your computer where running your server.

One more thing is that your server is probably local server, so ensure it and the phone connect in the same network.